# Javascript function not defined but it does

Tags: javascript, jquery

My page's code is:

```
<!--Custom JavaScript -->
// --> This Script contains the initLoadMore function <--
<script src="/static/js/custom.min.js"></script>    

<script src="/static/js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/material-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script>
   $(function(){
      initLoadMore("btnLoadMoreEvents","events-list");
   });
</script>
```

the Script custom.min.js contains:

```
$(function(){
function initLoadMore(btnLoadMore,container){
    let num_page = 2;
    $("#"+btnLoadMore).click(function(){
        $.get("?p="+num_page).done(function(data) {
            $("#"+btnLoadMore).prop("disabled",true);
            if(data.last_page == true){
                $("#"+container).append(data.content);
                $("#"+btnLoadMore).remove();
            }else{
                $("#"+container).append(data.content);
                num_page = num_page + 1;
            }
       }).fail(function(xhr){
            swal("Error", "Ha ocurrido un error al cargar m\u00E1s contenido. Por favor, int\u00e9ntalo de nuevo.", "error");
       }).always(function(){
           $("#"+btnLoadMore).prop("disabled",false);
       });
    });
}
});
```

The console says `Uncaught ReferenceError: initLoadMore is not defined`. The function only works if I delete the `$(function(){ ... });`(document ready) in the `custom.min.js` Script.

Why does this happen?

Comment: `initLoadMore` is _local_ function, accessible inside the container function scope.

Comment: As @Tushar mentioned, the fact that you're using a `$(function(){})` wrapper, the function `initLoadMore()` gets its own scope which means it is not visible from the outside. *Do you require the* `$(function(){})` *wrapper and if so, why is it necessary?*

Comment: You don't need to wrap the `initLoadMore` function in `ready`. Because, you're defining it, not invoking it.

Comment: Why are you even using this `(function() {})();` encapsultation? It does nothing else but declaring `initLoadMore`

Comment: Use `$(function(){})` when you are invoking something straight away. `function(){}` or `() => {}` or `arg => {}` are `anonymous` functions which means they get invoked at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

`initLoadMore` is local function You you can't acces it from other side

if you remove `$(function(){}` then it's works well.

> `$(function(){}` is like a `private access modifier`. So you can call the defined  function only inside the scope itself.

Comment: _The function only works if I delete the $(function(){ ... });_

Comment: @Tushar Updated :)

Answer (score 1):

Your function is encapsulated in another function, so it is not globally available.

If you remove the `$(function(){ ... });` part around the function, you declare it as a global function and other scripts will be able to call it.

In order to encapsulate the function, while still calling it last, perhaps you could call the script  last, and invoke it directly like this:

```
(function(){
//do something
}());
```